# Elm - retrieving string via get request

Tags: http, elm

I am trying to make a get request to retrieve a string

When I use

```
retrieve : Task.Task Http.Error String
retrieve = getString "http://api.endpoint.com"
```

everything works fine.

On the other hand if I use

```
retrieve : Task.Task Http.Error String
retrieve = get Json.Decode.string "http://api.endpoint.com"
```

the http request gets done, but the chained tasks are not executed.

My question is: what is the difference between the two approaches above? Am I doing something wrong with the second one? How to debug it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getString` returns the response of the get request as a `String`. `get` take a JSON decoder and runs that over the response of the get request. So if you provide `Json.Decode.string`, it will expect the response to be have a Json encoded string in it. So it expects extra double quotes in the response.

If your http request fails the best way to debug is to look at what kind of error you get. In this case you'll probably get an `UnexpectedPayload` because the request succeeds, but the decoder fails.